# Sweetalert2 modal loads briefly before image appears in modal

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I'm using Sweetalert2 to display a modal that has an image inside. Although it works fine, the modal without the image shows for a split second before the image appears. How can I wait until the image fully loads. Here's what I've tried that doesn't work: (loadPage is called when the page loads.)

```
    function loadPage() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () { setTimeout(function () { getToast(); }, 5000); }
    img.src = "Images/Save.png";
}

function getToast() {
    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: false,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'close',
        timer: 6000,
        imageUrl: 'Images/Save.png',
        timerProgressBar: true,
        title: 'My message.',
    })
    Toast.fire({

    })
}
```

Comment: due to the css styles (interactions with the flex sizes) used, there's an issue with reflow when the height of the image is beyond a certain size, where there is an ugly flicker because the positioning of the image jumps.  You'll have to set the image size to a smaller size or append the image after the footer.  It is not due to preloading, and the other fix would be to manually force a size on the elements beforehand, which would require overriding the default styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing it should just work without any flicker. The image is downloaded, cached and on the subsequent requests it should be served from cache. I created a fiddle and could not reconstruct your described issue.

Although I created an alternative approach saving the downloaded image as an dataURI and passing it to your SweetAlert instance. This way you can prevent accidentally downloading the image multiple times.

```js
function loadPage() {

    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var dataURL;
      canvas.height = this.height;
      canvas.width = this.width;
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('canvas');
      setTimeout(function () { getToast(dataURL); }, 1000);
      canvas = null;
    };
  img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png';
}

function getToast(dataURL) {
    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: false,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'close',
        timer: 6000,
        imageUrl: dataURL,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        title: 'My message.',
    })
    Toast.fire({

    })
}

loadPage()
```

Also see the attached fiddle for a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/4sza8u2m/